# There is a binary version available but the source version is later: binary source needs_compilation... y/n/cancel - How to und the answer?

Tags: r

I am a beginner and just starting my first semester with R Studios. I had to install Mosaic and mistakenly answered yes. Now when I run `library(mosaic)` I get an error. Can I change the question?

[image]

If I delete the packages and reinstall, I get the same error. I hope you can help me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Run `install.packages("tibble")`

Comment: It is unfortunate that the error message is misleading. There is of course a package named “tibble”. It just hadn’t been installed as part of the installation of the “mosaic” package. I think that error message should be rewritten to say that one should first try to install “tibble”.

Comment: The question in the title is a different issue, however, and it is very likely that you should simply answer ‘no’.